# SAS - Reading value from one observation into a another observation

Tags: macros, sas

I'm using SAS and I'm trying to read an observation's value from a previous observation into a current observation.

here's what the data looks like

```
Obs URN       Description Error_Bucket inputAcctNumber             count 
1 010001234567 Base      Invalid Name  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 1 
2 010001234567 No Error  No Error          0                          2 
3 010007891023 No Error  No Error      BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 1 
4 010007891023 A2/J2     Invalid Name      0                          2 
5 010004567890 No Error  No Error      CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC 1 
6 010004567890 A2/J2     Invalid Name      0                          2 
7 010001354321 No Error  No Error      DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 1
```

I have created the Count field and in this example there are only two observations with the same URN, but in the future there could be 3 - N number of observations with the same URN number. What I'm trying to do is give all of these observations the same InputAcctNumber that have the same URN number, but right now they are all 0's. How can I do this, especially if the number of "counts" with the urn are ambiguous.

Ideally this is what I want my data to look like:

```
    Obs URN       Description Error_Bucket inputAcctNumber             count 
1 010001234567 Base      Invalid Name  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 1 
2 010001234567 No Error  No Error      AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 2 
3 010007891023 No Error  No Error      BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 1 
4 010007891023 A2/J2     Invalid Name  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 2 
5 010004567890 No Error  No Error      CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC 1 
6 010004567890 A2/J2     Invalid Name  CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC 2 
7 010001354321 No Error  No Error      DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 1
```

Comment: Is the record with the valid AcctNumber always the one with COUNT=1?  Is it possible to have more than one record with a valid AcctNumber? If so is it possible for the values to be different? If so which one do you want to use?

Comment: The populated account number within each URN group should always be Count 1. There could be an instance where 2/3 accounts have a populated account number and share an URN number

Comment: So if one URN can have two account numbers then which one do you want to use?  You could get it to one by only using the record where COUNT=1.

Comment: the 2/3 accounts would/should be the same number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is just to merge the inputAcctNumber variable back onto the data.

```
data want ;
  merge have (drop=inputAcctNumber )
        have (keep=URN inputAcctNumber where=(inputAcctNumber ne '0'))
  ;
  by URN;
run;
```

If the first record always has the right number then you could make a new variable and retain the value.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  by urn count ;
  if first.urn then new=inputAcctNumber;
  retain new;
  drop inputAcctNumber;
  rename new=inputAcctNumber;
run;
```

Comment: this will give it to any number of observations where count NE 1?

Comment: It will take the first value of inputAcctNumber and copy it onto all records for that value of URN.  So yes it will handle any number of records per URN (ie any values of COUNT).

Comment: which part of this code is actually creating the Acct_numb in the second, third, nth observations? I see if first.urn then new=acctnumb, but that would only satisfying the observation where count = 0 since it's first. Is the retain new statement holding the value of acctnumb from one iteration of urn to the next?

Comment: Yes. The purpose of the retain statement is to prevent SAS from resetting the variable to missing at the start of the next iteration of the data step.

Comment: So, at the start of the next value of "URN" within the group of "URNS", where one urn can be >1?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question?  The value of NEW stays the same until it is modified by the next time the assignment statement runs.  That will happen when the value of URN changes because it is checking FIRST.URN automatic variable. The only purpose COUNT has in this code is that the data step will generate an error if the values of count within each value of URN are not in non-decreasing order.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a way to do what you asked, using PROC SQL.  I do this by creating 4 different tables, with the last one being the one you wanted.  This may not be the most efficient way for you to do this, but you know your data better than I do.

Code:

```
proc sql noprint; 
  create table b as 
    select * 
      from a
        where count eq 1;

  create table c as
    select * 
      from a 
        where count ne 1;

  create table d as
    select c.URN, c.Description, c.Error_Bucket, b.inputAcctNumber, c.count
      from b b inner join c c
        on b.urn=c.URN
          order by URN;

  create table e as
    select * 
      from b
      outer union corresponding
    select *
      from c
        order by URN; 
quit;
```

Output with a proc print of dataset 'e':

```
Obs URN Description Error_Bucket inputAcctNumber count 
1 10001234567 No Error No Error  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 2 
2 10001234567 Base Invalid Name  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 1 
3 10001354321 No Error No Error  DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD 1 
4 10004567890 No Error No Error  CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC 1 
5 10004567890 A2/J2 Invalid Name CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC 2 
6 10007891023 A2/J2 Invalid Name BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 2 
7 10007891023 No Error No Error  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 1
```

Full Explanation:

(1) I made a table of rows with 'count' equal to 1.
(2) I made another table where 'count' is not equal to 1.
(3) I then did an inner join of the table made in (2) on the one made in (1) with 'inputAcctNumber' from table made in (1) instead of the one made in (2).
(4) I then appended the table made in (3) to the one made in (1) and then sorted by 'URN'.

Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: I don't see which part of the code is giving the acount number values to both observations and not just "null" or 0 to it...

Comment: When I create table d assigns the valid inputAcctNumber to the inputAcctNumber with missing value based on the inner join of matching URN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `retain` statement to get SAS to retain a previous records value in a datastep.

*Assuming* the data can be sorted so that records with valid `inputAcctNumber` occur first, you can use code like this:

```
proc sort; by URN count;

data test_output (drop=replacement);
 length replacement $50;
 retain replacement;
 set test_input;
 if trim(inputAcctNumber) = '0' then inputAcctNumber=replacement;
 output;
 if trim(inputAcctNumber) ne '0' then replacement=inputAcctNumber;
run;
```

Comment: I could just sort by URN, Count, Then Account Number and this should always work, correct?

Comment: I just altered the code to deal with more than two rows per URN.  Assuming that the URN with the valid inputAcctNumber come before the zeros, it show work.  It worked on the example data you showed.